# how to get data from web server to iphone or ipod

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm quite new in iPhone development and I need to develop an app.
I must get mp3 data from a web server, which provides a simple saving the mp3 in my app document or folder

and use it in an application, which should also dislpay a table with rows like:

song1
song2
song3

But at present I don't know at all how to get this web page, parse it and store into an array in the application.
Please do you have any suggestion / hint / sample code ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial on the apple developer site on how to make a http request and receive data [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). Should get you going on how to fetch the web page.

For parsing you can use the [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or a XML/HTML parser library like [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML) depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I used web services to communicate with web server, the following tutorial helped me a lot.
http://icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/

I was able to send and retrieve binary content using web service but I had to encode it first to be able to send it through Soap request and decode back Soap Response.
Hope that can help you,